# Hot Springs Spa will not heat

Tags: hot-tub

My 2005 Hot Springs Envoy spa will not heat.

- Heater light is on.
- On the circuit board:

  - Lim Ok has green light,
  - HTR On has Red light.
- Circulation pump is running.
- Heater Relay Board and wires going to heater:

  - Black wire reads 17V,
  - White 121V,
  - Red 121V,
  - combo or Red & White 214V.

I'm not sure why the Black would read 17V. Is that normal? Do you think I need a new relay board or heater?

Heater placard says 240V 4KW SSE-00-0H-0f was red tape

Comment: Can you post pictures of the wiring?

Comment: Your last sentence seems to be missing something. Care to [edit] and finish your thought?

Comment: Also, does this [related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32983/why-is-my-1997-hot-springs-sovereign-hot-tub-not-heating?rq=1) help?

Comment: Turn off the power and check all your connections. I had a connector actually melt that connected the heating element to the controls.  I eliminated the connector by hard wiring it. Be extra careful around hot tubs, their is a lot of power there.

Comment: Are there fuses for the heater elements? There are on many of them. If one fuse blows, no current flows to the elements, even though everything else tells you that it is running. The 17V makes it sound like that's the issue, because you are likely reading through a small transformer  or sensor on the load side of the fuses that is tapping off of one leg to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fuse or some other safety has opened. Black to red on the heater is usually 240v  with an intact heater and an open fuse on the black you will still read voltage as some is coming through the heater.